# How to bind gridview through linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using Linq-to-SQL.

Currently I am binding gridview through linq which query written in business logic call. I have extract record through query in business logic class and I want to bind that particular data to gridview and return data.

How to return data which type is array?

The code is here:

```
CMSBusiness.DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var cate = 
      from p in db.categoryTables
      select new 
      {
           categoryId=p.categoryId,
           categoryName=p.categoryName,
           categoryDesc=p.categoryDesc
      };
```

How to return value and bind gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
gridView.DataSource = cate;
```

, this should work. 
We also recommend you to take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546190.aspx).